# While using site: codeforces. I got struck with the user input. How to construct my code according to sites like this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I uploaded this code by selecting both JS V8 Engine & NodeJS.

But online compiler somehow showing correct result with saying wrong output.

Checker comment: wrong output format Unexpected end of file - token expected

```
const w = (weight) => {
  //
  if (weight % 2 === 0 && ((weight / 2) % 2 === 0)) {
      console.log(`YES`);
  } else {
    console.log(`NO`);
  }
};
```

Comment: It's dynamic: w(n)

Comment: the function returns after the "No" for example also undefined because of the console.log.
Maybe that is the reason?

Comment: It's not the case. This code to get the input from console. Because of this I can't use prompt(). My Question is how to configure my code or my node for this UserInput_feature. Execute in the browser console